# Perl, shift if(@_)

Tags: perl

Can someone tell me what

```
shift if(@_)
```

means in perl?

and so what would

```
sub id {
   my $self = shift;
   $self->{ID} = shift if @_;

   return $self->{ID};
}
```

mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sub, `shift` without argument uses `@_` array.

So

```
$self->{ID} = shift if @_;
```

is equal to

```
$self->{ID} = shift(@_) if @_;
```

(remove leftmost element from `@_` array and assign it to `$self->{ID}`)

Comment: [RETRACTED] In this case it could just be `$self->{ID} = shift`. it returns undef either way if an ID is not specified.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen They differ if the `ID` field is already filled in. The original code only overwrites it if there's a parameter, yours will replace it with `undef` if there's no parameter.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen they also differ in whether an ID key will always exist

Answer (score 5):

That is a handrolled accessor/mutator for an object

```
print $obj->id;       # Accessor form
$obj->id(NEW_VAL);    # Mutator form
```

It is functionally equivalent to:

```
sub id {
    my $self = shift;
    if (@_) { # If called with additional parameters, set the value:
         $self->{ID} = shift(@_);
    }
    return $self->{ID};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`shift` takes the first element off an array and returns it.  If no array is given, it operates on `@_`, the array containing function arguments.  The `if @_` statement modifier causes the preceding statement to be executed only if `@_` has at least one element.

In your example, `$self->{ID} = shift @_ if @_;` means "If there is a function argument, assign it to `$self->{ID}`.

Answer (score 1):

`shift if(@_)` says "if `@_` has any elements (i.e., evaluating `@_` in scalar context is greater than zero), shift off the first element of the default argument (inside a subroutine, this is `@_`)".

The sub is a standard pre-Moose setter/getter method. Commented to explain:

```
sub id {
    my $self = shift;   # @_ is the implied argument of shift.
                        # Since method calls prepend the object reference to @_,
                        # this grabs the object itself, assumed by the later code
                        # to be a hash reference.

    $self->{ID} = shift if @_;
                        # If there's still anything left in @_ (`if @_`), get
                        # the first item and stash it under the ID key in 
                        # the hash referenced by $self (note that if there is more
                        # than one item, we'll only stash the first one).

    return $self->{ID}; # Return whatever the value of the item stored under ID in the
                        # hash referenced by $self is. This will be the value just 
                        # assigned if the method was called with a scalar argument, 
                        # or whatever value was there before if no argument was passed.
                        # This will be undef if nothing was ever stored under the ID key.
}
```

Invocation would be

```
$obj->id();
```

to fetch, and

```
$obj->id($value);
```

to set.

A standard pre-Moose constructor would create an anonymous hash reference, `bless` it to turn it into an object (connecting a package implementing the class's behavior to that reference), and return it:

```
sub new {
    my($class) = @_;     # List assignment to a list; puts first item in one into the first
                         # item in another; a call to a class method prepends the package
                         # (class) name to @_, so this gets us the name of the class this
                         # object is to belong to.
    my $self = {};       # Gets a new anonymous hash reference into $self.
    bless $self, $class; # Connects the hash reference to the package, so that method calls
                         # made on this object are directed to this class (and its @ISA
                         # ancestors) to find the sub to be called to implement the method.
    return $self;        # Hands the object back to the caller.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `shift if @_` in your example -- `if` applies to the entire statement, not just the `shift` expression (because `if` has very low precedence in the expression hierarchy).

```
$self->{ID} = shift if @_;
```

is short for:

```
if (@_) {
    $self->{ID} = shift;
}
```

`shift` with no argument pulls the first element off the `@_` list, so this sets `$self->{ID}` to the first argument of the subroutine if there are any arguments.

The general rule regarding postfix use of `if` is that:

```
<expression1> if <expression2>;
```

is short for:

```
if (<expression2>) {
    <expression1>;
}
```